# Loop of a loop in R

Tags: r, loops

This is my problem: I have two different data frames (A and B). The column of each data frame is a geographical locality and the row data are the species in a locality. I need to intersect the list of species of the locality 1 of the data fame A with the list of species of all the localities of the data frame B. To do this I wrote a loop like this:

```
res<-list()
for(i in 1:length(B)) {intersect(A[1], B[i])->res[[i]]
}
```

Now I have to repeat the same loop for the locality 2, 3, 4, 5,6,..... of A, that is to say I have to intersect all the localities of A with all the localities of B.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Questions are easier to answer if you provide sample data.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a similar approach to nested loops that uses `lapply()`.

If you have a large dataset, using `lapply()` may gain you very considerable speed improvements over using loops. Loops are slow in R, and it is recommended to use vectorized functions in [the `*apply` family](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7141669/19410) where possible.

I'll walk through an example and you can perhaps adapt it to your dataset.

First, we make a sample 3x3 data frame called `df`, with columns `a`, `b` and `c`, and rows `d`, `e` and `f`:

```
> df <- data.frame(a = sample(3), b = sample(3), c = sample(3))
> rownames(df) <- c('d','e','f')
```

Let's look at `df` and its transpose `t(df)`:

```
> df
  a b c
d 3 1 3
e 1 3 1
f 2 2 2

> t(df)
  d e f
a 3 1 2
b 1 3 2
c 3 1 2
```

Let's say we want to `intersect` the column vectors of `df` and `t(df)`. We now use nested `lapply()` statements to run `intersect()` on column vectors from both `df` and the transpose `t(df)`:

```
> result <- lapply(df, function(x) lapply(as.data.frame(t(df)), function(y) intersect(x,y)))
```

The results are a `list()`, showing the intersection results:

```
> is.list(result)
[1] TRUE

> print(result)
$a
$a$d
[1] 3 1

$a$e
[1] 3 1

$a$f
[1] 2


$b
$b$d
[1] 1 3

$b$e
[1] 1 3

$b$f
[1] 2


$c
$c$d
[1] 3 1

$c$e
[1] 3 1

$c$f
[1] 2
```

Let's look at `df` and `t(df)` again, and see how to read these results:

```
> df
  a b c
d 3 1 3
e 1 3 1
f 2 2 2

> t(df)
  d e f
a 3 1 2
b 1 3 2
c 3 1 2
```

Let's look at `df$a` intersected with `t(df)$d`, `t(df)$e` and `t(df)$f`:

```
$a
$a$d
[1] 3 1
```

Intersecting the vectors `a` and `d`: `{3,1,2}^{3,1,3} = {3,1}`

```
$a$e
[1] 3 1
```

Again, with vectors `a` and `e`: `{3,1,2}^{1,3,1} = {3,1}`

```
$a$f
[1] 2
```

And lastly, with vectors `a` and `f`: `{3,1,2}^{2,2,2} = {2}`

The other items in `result` follow.

To extend this to your dataset, think of your data-frame columns as *localities*, and the transposed-data-frame columns as your *species*. Then use `lapply()`, as shown above.

---

To break down the nested `lapply()` statement, start with the inner `lapply()`:

```
lapply(as.data.frame(t(df)), function(y) ... )
```

What this means is that every column vector in `t(df)` — the columns $d, $e and $f — are represented by the variable `y` in `function(y)`. We'll come back to `...` in a second.

Now let's look at the outer `lapply()`:

```
lapply(df, function(x) ... )
```

What this means is that every column vector in `df` — columns $a, $b and $c — are represented by variable `x` in `function(x)`.

Now let's explain `...`.

The outer `...` is any function of `x` — this can be `length()`, `sum()`, etc. and even another `lapply()`. The inner `lapply()` has its own function and variable name `y`, and so the inner `...` can run a function on both `x` and `y`.

So that's what we do: For every column vector in `df`, we run a function on that `df`-vector and every column vector in the transpose `t(df)`. In our example, the function we will run on `x` and `y` is `intersect()`:

```
> result <- lapply(df, function(x) lapply(as.data.frame(t(df)), function(y) intersect(x,y)))
```

Comment: This is a very interesting procedure. This is the first way I experimented but only now I can understand how lapply works. The explanation is very useful. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's difficulty to fully understand what you want to obtain as a result. But if I guessed correctly your needs the code below will do what you want. This code can be further optimized of course to improve speed, because for big datasets it may work not too fast.

```
res <- list()
for (i in 1:ncol(A)) {
  res[[i]] <- list()
  for (j in 1:ncol(B)) {
    res[[i]][[j]] <- intersect(A[,i], B[,j])
  }
}
```

To access result you can use

```
res[[column_index_in_A]][[column_index_in_B]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a wild guess at your data:

```
A <- data.frame(
  London     = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
  Manchester = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE),
  Birmingham = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE),  
  row.names  = c("rats", "mice", "foxes")
)

B <- data.frame(
    London     = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),
    Manchester = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE),
    Birmingham = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
    row.names  = c("rats", "mice", "foxes")    
)


> A
      London Manchester Birmingham
rats    TRUE      FALSE       TRUE
mice    TRUE       TRUE      FALSE
foxes  FALSE      FALSE       TRUE
> B
      London Manchester Birmingham
rats    TRUE       TRUE       TRUE
mice   FALSE       TRUE       TRUE
foxes  FALSE       TRUE      FALSE
```

In this case, to find species that exist in the same location in both datasets, you just need

```
as.matrix(A) & as.matrix(B)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to focuse the attention on the intersection of faunal lists as I need to compute a similariry index